# Как правильно хранить изменения в полях таблицы mysql?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Допустим есть таблица `products` с полями `id,name,price,created_at,updated_at` . Нужно мониторить как изменялась к примеру цена товара. Логика такая : лежат в бд товары , время от времени в базу будет добавляться тот самый товар(название то самое) и возможно с другой ценой . Как лучше всего записывать изменения в цене, чтобы потом было удобно работать с ней (сортировать, группировать товары по ней и т.д)? 
Создать таблицу `product_price_changes`, где записывать предыдущие цены? и в перспективе может понадобиться мониторить изменения еще других полей ,тогда на каждое поле нужна отдельная таблица получается . 
Или добавлять в ту же таблицу `products` данные о продукте  ,но тогда может получится что таблице могут быть почти одинаковы записи(`1,товар1,100,created_at,updated_at`) и (`2,товар1,110,created_at,updated_at`) и это по-моему не совсем правильно .
подскажите , как правильно спроектировать бд в таком случае?

Comment: или отдельную таблицу практически с такой же структурой как products со всеми полями плюс возможно дата операции, тип операции. В этой таблице хранить старые версии записей о продукте, целиком

Comment: Исключить изменение и удаление записей, вместо изменения добавлять новую запись с обновлёнными значениями полей. В структуру добавить поле валидности записи, при удалении или вставке откорректированной записи текущую помечать как невалидную.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таблица лога. id, table_name, field_name, changed_at, old_value, new_value

Comment: И триггер на эту таблицу, при UPDATE и INSERT в products